# How do I add a breakpoint for all occurrences of a word in a Visual Studio 2010 solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

I search for a word (could be a column name, variable name, etc.) in the entire solution and I wish to keep a breakpoint at all occurrences. Say I get some 500 occurrences in about 50 files. What is the easiest way to place breakpoints at ALL those occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>F8</kbd> means go to the next occurrence of Find In Files.
<kbd>F9</kbd> means set a breakpoint at the current line.

So all you have to do is spend a couple of minutes playing [Track & Field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Track_%26_Field_(video_game)) with the <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd> keys.

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for something where I can add those 500 breakpoints in one shot, if possible?